# Aura component replace highlighted text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, richtextarea, lightning-inputfield, inputrichtext

Hi I want to be able to have the user highlight text in a `lightning:inputRichText` component and then be able to replace it with a link. I am able to get the highlighted text with `window.getSelection()`. However I am unable to find the range of that highlighted portion with

```javascript
let text = document.getElementsByClassName("textarea")
console.log(text.selectionStart)
```

The console log is undefined however the text variable is valid and not null.

Does anyone have a solution to get the index of the highlighted text.

Context: I am building a custom link button for the lightning:inputRichText component

Edit:

```javascript
let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range.deleteContents();
var div = document.createElement("div"); 
const newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
div.appendChild(newContent); 
range.insertNode(div);
```

I am trying like above. It does remove the highlighted text but then throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit') throws at

Comment: let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
        range.deleteContents();
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        const newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
        div.appendChild(newContent);
        range.insertNode(div); 

I am trying like above. It does remove the highlighted text but then throws and error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit') throws at

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Glad you were able to find a solution on your own. But since SFSE is a Questions & Answers site, rather than adding "SOLVED" and the solution code to your question, it is acceptable (actually encouraged) to answer your own question and select your own answer. It makes it obvious to future readers and might help someone with the same or a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

```
let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0),
    desiredLink = 'www.nba.com', 
    desiredText = window.getSelection().toString();
range.deleteContents();
let el = document.createElement("a");
el.setAttribute('href',desiredLink);
el.innerHTML = desiredText;
range.insertNode(el);
```